# one term two taxonomy's?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

Anybody got any solutions for this...

I'm building an app where I have two heirchical custom taxnomies acting as custom categories. So i've got cat1 and cat2 taxonomy.

What I want to do is copy a term, along with its children from cat1 to cat2. Maybe something like:

```
set_term_taxonomy($term_id, array("cat1, "cat2"));
```

where the same term, along with its children, could be in more than one taxonomy. The reason for 2 taxonomies is that they are 2 different shop inventories.

Comment: so far all I can think of is writing a routine to loop through a term and its children, then recreate each term in the new taxonomy, giving the effect of it being copied across

Comment: keep in mind that slug is a unique key in the wp_terms table, you can't have two taxonomies share the same slug.

Comment: @Milo yeh and there lies the wall. I'm going to have to write a function to loop through the ancestry. I'll post it back here when its done. Some one might find it usefull ;)

Answer (score 1):

Had to write a method to do it. Here is the method... hope it helps someone else ;)

syntax:

```
copy_terms($term->term_id, "taxonomy1", "taxonomy2", 0); //will copy to root of destination



 /**
 * Copy a term and its descendants from one taxonomy to another.
 * Both taxonomies have to be hierarchical. Will copy across 
 * posts as well.
 *
 * @param int $term the term id to copy
 * @param string $from the taxonomy of the original term
 * @param string $to the destination for the taxonomy
 * @param int $parent the parent term_id to add the taxonomy to
 * @return type true|WP_Error
 */
function copy_terms($term, $from, $to, $parent=0) {

    //check for child terms      
    $term = get_term($term, $from);
    $child_terms = get_terms($from, array(
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => $term->term_id
            ));

    //check for child products
    $child_prods = new WP_Query(array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $from,
                    'terms' => $term->term_id
                )
            )
        ));

    //work out new slug
    if($parent==0) $slug = $to."-".sanitize_title($term->name);
    else{
        $parent_term = get_term($parent, $to);
        $slug = $parent_term->slug."-".sanitize_title($term->name);
    }

    //add term to new taxonomy
    $parent = wp_insert_term($term->name, $to, array(
        'description' => $term->description,
        'parent' => $parent,
        'slug' => $slug
            ));

    if(is_wp_error($parent)) return $parent;
    $parent = get_term($parent['term_id'], $to);        
    if(is_wp_error($parent)) return $parent;

    //loop through folders first
    foreach($child_terms as $child){
        copy_terms($child->term_id, $from, $to, $parent->term_id);
    }

    //loop through products
    foreach($child_prods->posts as $child){
        wp_set_post_terms($child->ID, $parent->term_id, $to, true);
    }
    return true;
```